# Conditional assignement of column values in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have an excel sheet with 3 columns, which I read into a dataframe df:

[image]

df  prints properly.

Now I need to add 2 new columns based on the above 3 columns

[image]
Below is the function I wrote for that and it doesn't evaluate properly

```
def setData(FinalCombinedSet):
    if(df['age']==np.nan):
        df['Final Column']='age column blank'
        df['Mumbai category']='NO'
        return df
    elif(df['name']=='def' and df['place']=='Mumbai'):
        df['Final column'] = 'category Mumbai'
        df['Mumbai category']='YES'
        return df
    else:
        df['Final Column'] = 'Other values'
        df['Mumbai category']='NO'
        return  df
df=df.apply(lambda df:setData(df),axis=1)
```

Comment: the issue might be in line ```elif(df['name']=='def' and df['place']=='Mumbai'):``` of your function. since only row in your data with `name` == `def` have value of column `place` as `Mubai` and not `Mumbai` hence above logic is false for all rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.select` for vectorized approach:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"name":["abc","def","ghi"],
                   "age":["","20","22"],
                   "place":["Bangalore","Mumbai","Mumbai"]})

df["final column"] = np.select([df["age"]=="",(df["name"]=="def")&(df["place"]=="Mumbai")],
                               ['age column blank','category Mumbai'],
                               default="Other values")
df['Mumbai category'] = np.select([df["age"]=="",(df["name"]=="def")&(df["place"]=="Mumbai")],
                               ["NO","YES"],
                               default="NO")

print (df)

#
  name age      place      final column Mumbai category
0  abc      Bangalore  age column blank              NO
1  def  20     Mumbai   category Mumbai             YES
2  ghi  22     Mumbai      Other values              NO
```

Comment: Hi Friend this method is working. But for some reason I need to check the conditions the way I put in order. Is there any way to execute in that order and assigne accordingly.

Comment: It is already in the order of your conditions. `np.select([list_of_conditions],[list_of_results],default="default_value")`

Comment: Henry but df["age"]=="" doesnt work, because that column contains nan... df['age']==np.nan doesn't work

Comment: How can I include this nan check into this condition list

Comment: Use `df["age"].isnull()` instead if the data contains `NaN`. You didn't include that in your sample data so I assumed all your empty datas are string instead.